# javascript events not apply in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to add some events to my page with a loop. this is my code

```
elements = $(".my-elements")
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    e = elements[i];
    document.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
        if( inViewport(e) ) {
            $(e).css({opacity: 1.0})
        }
    })
}
```

But after running the code, only the last event is applied, and previous events have no effect.
what's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
elements = $(".my-elements")
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    function() {
        var e = elements[i];
        document.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
            if( inViewport(e) ) {
                $(e).css({opacity: 1.0})
            }
        })
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the method is running synchronously,
try to put it into an [async method][1], await for the function inside it and return a promise in each iteration.
it will stop the execution of the async function until one iteration is completed
like-

```js
async function myEvent(){


  elements = $(".my-elements")
  var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      await function() {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          var e = elements[i];
           document.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
             if( inViewport(e) ) {
                  $(e).css({opacity: 1.0})
                  resolve();
              }else{
                  resolve();
              }
          })
    
     })
  }
  }
}
```

if there's an error in snippet you can correct it but take my point of going async.
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function